# How to force rendering of video tag content while chrome/electron window is not active for screen sharing?

Tags: google-chrome, electron, html5-video, screensharing

My website have `<video>` tag for showing `.mp4` video.

I use [screen sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) feature of [Google Meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Meet) and Zoom for my online meeting where I generally share [Chrome's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) window to the audiance.

Everything works well except content of `<video>` tag when chrome window is not active or hidden behind other windows. I see blank area where `<video>` tags content should appear.

`Case 1: When chrome winodw is active`
All content of my website is visible properly to audiance.

`Case 2: When chrome's window is hidden behind other applications window`
I see everything execept content of `<video>` tag

`Case 3: When Chrome's window is minimized`
Nothing is visible to audiance which is ok

I observed this behaviour in both Chrome and Electron window.

I want to override `Case 2`, So how can I force Chrome and electron window to render content of `<video>` tag even when their windows are not active.

Answer (score 4):

**In Chrome**
open `chrome://flags` and disable `#calculate-native-win-occlusion`

**In electron.js**
Pass `backgroundThrottling: false` in `webPreferences` while creating new `BrowserWindow` like

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      backgroundThrottling: false
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is what I had been looking for. This also help to render the screen even when other software enter full-screen.